# Javascript file included multiple times with JSF / Liferay 6.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, jsf-2.2

I'm running with Liferay 6.2 and JSF 2.2.12

I have two custom portlets (using Primefaces). 
My portlets import Javascript resources using `<h:head />`.
Those portlets are displayed on the same page.

On my staging environment `primefaces.js` is included once in the rendered view :

```
<script src="https://example.com/group/my-site/url?p_p_id=portletone_WAR_portletone&...javax.faces.resource=primefaces.js...">
```

Why do I get two `<script>` in production environment :

```
<script src="https://example.com/group/my-site/url?p_p_id=portletone_WAR_portletone&...javax.faces.resource=primefaces.js...">
<script src="https://example.com/group/my-site/url?p_p_id=portlettwo_WAR_portlettwo&...javax.faces.resource=primefaces.js...">
```

(same observation with `jquery.js`)

Comment: You are using an old version of Liferay Faces and JSF. You should upgrade to the appropriate versions which can be found on https://liferayfaces.org in order to avoid security vulnerabilities.

Comment: yunandtidus, has correctly identified the problem and solution for Liferay 6.2, but people should be aware that a similar problem can occur for Liferay 7.0+ as well: [FACES-3175](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-3175). We've fixed this issue in Bridge Ext 5.0.3, so upgrading to that version should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to Liferay Parallel Rendering. In order to disable parallel rendering, add the following property to **`portal-ext.properties`**

```
layout.parallel.render.enable=false
```

All credit goes to Neil Griffin on the Liferay Forums: 
https://community.liferay.com/fr/forums/-/message_boards/message/20947470#_com_liferay_message_boards_web_portlet_MBPortlet_message_36195975